# I can't uninstall Spotify from my phone

Tags: applications, 7.0-nougat

I've received the Nougat update today on my Xperia Z5 today. I tried to uninstall Spotify after updating for some reason, but I couldn't find the Uninstall button; All I can find is the Disable button, it's acting like a bloatware. What can I do to remove it?

[image]

Comment: [Same issue on Spotify forum](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Android/How-do-I-completely-uninstall-a-pre-installed-Spotify-app-from/td-p/1438448): either use custom ROM, or root the phone to uninstall it...

Comment: Maybe it got added on your phone as a bloatware after the update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may came as system app with latest update.
So you can only uninstall using [System App Remover](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jumobile.manager.systemapp&hl=en) or you can't.

You may disable app.

Hope will help you!

Answer (score 0):

The app can't be uninstalled because it's in-built(pre-loaded). However, you can disable the app. Disabling is just like uninstalling apart from the fact that it will still consume space.

Edit: One way to remove the app is by rooting your phone.